# How to store a json response in a variable

Tags: python

```
params = {                                                                      #API parameters
        'returnFaceId': 'false',
        'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
        'returnFaceAttributes': 'smile',
    }

    response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params,
                             headers=headers, json={"url": image_url})
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))
```

output:
[{"faceRectangle": {"top": 125, "left": 154, "width": 94, "height": 94}, "faceAttributes": {"smile": 1.0}}]

I want to access the smile attribute and store it into a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: `response.json()` returns a dictionary if I recall correctly. Have you tried accessing it like a dictionary?

Comment: the response is as list with one json entry

Comment: It seems that what you're missing is to work through a Python JSON tutorial or documentation page.  JSON format and Python dict are closely related, with many methods to convert between them.  You've already discovered `dumps`, which means you've found the general area of resources you need.

Comment: You're receiving downvotes because of the perceived lack of effort to have first read through the documentation or having researched options. Which is what @Prune is calling out. I just wanted to provide specific clarity to the downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'd access it in this example.
The return type is a `list of dictionaries`.

```
>>> response[0]['faceAttributes']['smile']
>>> 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access `smile` like this   no need to use  `json.dumps` . This is based on assumption it return array? Are you sure it returns array

For array response

```
      response.json[0]['faceAttributes']['smile']
```

For dictionary response

```
    response.json['faceAttributes']['smile']
```